# OpenGL axis convention

Tags: opengl, camera, coordinates, axis

I'm writting for fun a graphic engine. And I'm stuck in a deep convention problem.

I know the default OpenGL axis convention, X+ is right, Y+ is top and Z- is the way you see things on screen. To be clear, without touching the default configuration, if I want to see something, I need to draw it in Z- in the world, if I draw it in Z+ it will be "behind the camera". I want to stick to that convention.

In other hand, for objects, in their local axis, I use X+ for right too, y+ for top too, but Z+ for the front. So If I draw a guy, his eyes look toward Z+. I like this convention too, but I'm unsure, because it's a bit weird with the way we render the world, after all it's fine.

Now, here is the real problem I had. When it come to use light (and shadow mapping), I will just take spot light for the example. Should I use Z+ or Z- to point the lightray ?

Because here is the trick. If I want to use shadow mapping technic, we have the light by itself and a "camera" to draw things into the shadow map and I try to stick to an uniform "camera" convention, no matter what I'm rendering (default framebuffer, off-screen rendering for effects or shadow mappings).

I end up with light using Z- for ray to follow camera convention. But really, it bothers me. I can still to that convention, but it's weird when it came to create a function like lookAt(), basic mesh will "look at" correctly, but a light will be reversed... And finally what if I want a model to concretise my spot light for example ? The whole structure is a bit shitty...

My basic question is, what is the best convention I should use for a basic model/mesh rendering, a camera rendering the scene and a directional/spot light emitting ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the whole pipeline is quite confusing. If you are having trouble with seeing how the right hand coordinate system and world space (Z-) interrelate you could perhaps try visualizing it like this. Imagine the right hand coordinate system is a 2D plot with map coordinates, so that the Y axis points north, the x axis points east, and the "up" axis (perpendicular to the 2D plot) and therefore out of the screen. Then imagine being in a rocket launching from earth, you would assume the ascension direction is Z+.

[image: rocket launches along z+]

Therefore, things appear on camera when they are "below" the camera, or negative z, and are in "world space". So, really it makes sense to have the camera z position increase positively as it gets further away, because it sort of works in a relativistic sense. Defining light positions and object positions however, it makes more sense to have Z+ because, they are the important features.

But, the projection matrix inverts the Z axis when going from world space to view space so that proper z buffer depth test/ fragment culling works as expected (ie. front pixels are further in the positive z direction), not exactly sure exactly if this make sense...

Edit: This is my current working knowledge, that obviously still may have some flaws, but if it opens up a discussion where we can both learn something, I will have found it worthwhile :)

Comment: Yes the whole thing is quite confusing, but I'm OK with this, I got solutions, but I don't like to "take care" wich convention to use in every situation. Sometimes, you forget a thing and as my shadow map last work, I was pretty sure to be in right Z axes to build the framebuffer, and finally not ! I finally ended with, for everything, forward is Z-, and now on my coordinates system, forward() still and should give me the Z+ vector, so I'd probably rename those functions like XVector(), YVector() and ZVector() to  avoid the confusion.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that it can be difficult wrapping your head around it. My general understanding of building a pipeline is that x,y,z coords of an object that I create are in local space and are centered around the origin until translated, which then puts them in world space. A camera, defined as a location and a direction is set up such that its position is defined as a translation of the world space origin and its direction is a rotation of the world space origin, usually confined to rotations about x and z only, to stop "gimbal lock" (still learning what that is too!)....

Comment: What I still don't quite grasp... If a camera is placed at (0,0,0) and an object is translated along the Z- axis, its position Z is getting smaller, as it shrinks in the camera view. Should "move camera backward" then be defined as the equivalent of moving the whole scene forward, ie. along the Z- axis? It's abit funny...

Comment: Yes that's the problem, if I want to make an FPS like game for example, my camera is pointing to Z-, so if I want to move forward, I should go toward Z-... And If i got some enemies, to be homogenous, they should use the same convention.

Comment: I could even fix somes rules, but it came very difficult with my spot light for example. I use a node based system, so the node holds the coordinates data. So, for my light I need to use these coordinates for, displaying the physical light model, then for emitting the light, and finally to build a specific framebuffer (camera like) to render the shadowmap. These three things can use different coordinates system convention but are based on the node coordinates... I wanted to avoid a lot of conversion.

Comment: And for the beauty of it, I reuse the node coordinates for the physics calculation too...

Comment: Okay I understand the question a bit better and am still quite unsure. I think the second part of my answer is abit confusing, I was thinking your question had to with why a triangle at z=-1 is drawn infront of triangle at z=0 if you don't include a projection matrix, which I was trying to understand/explain too. When theres too many details I know its time to bring up learnopengl again :) Sounds like you have a good system, your project sounds amazing, Physics too, i'd love to see it when its finished.

Comment: But to add, well yes, I think in an FPS, moving forward would be z decreasing, same with enemies, in your renderers coordinate system, but you could build a matrix that could invert this for convenience when building your game layer on top of it, hell maybe even converting to z-up, x-y ground plane would make it easier to understand for the game programming. Because z as depth is apparently historically defined, and there isn't much real need apart from that "its always been done that way". It irks me that z is thru the screen, and to make matters worse Z- is forward.

Comment: Here is that thread: https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/general-discussion/46691-z-up-vs-y-up-the-solution-to-the-debate-lies-within

Comment: *that the world is orientated around the camera, but thinking about thing this way just isn't practical when it comes to implementing them on top of the renderer, so we assume the camera moves through static coordinates, making much more sense to the user*

Comment: Yes I could separate things in "game coordinates system" and "rendering coordinates system" with a opaque conversion system for the top layer (game one).

Comment: You can see a demonstration here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKtRH6tlnUg